# Report Builder: Can I link to a specific part of a report?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I would like to link to a specific section of a report from another report. A quick search on the internet didn't give me any suggestions, so I thought I would ask you smart folks here ;-).

I'm really looking for something like anchors in HTML but for a report.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "specific section of a report"? From your question about something like HTML anchors i presume you just want to go to a report from another.This is drillthrough reporting.Not sure if you want this.

Comment: I mean something like clicking on a link from one report, and opening up the second page of another report for example, or show a specific table in the other report (rather than making the user search for the relevant information in that report). I hope  that clears it up a bit.

Comment: I am also looking for this functionality. Has there been any update in SSRS functionality to allow this? I would like to drill to another report and jump to a specific bookmark. Apologies as i did not want to ask a separate question but see if there were any updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know already the page of the report you want to jump, then instead of the action "Go to report" I think you should use "Go to URL" and in the expression field insert something like:

```
"http://myrsserver/reportserver?http://portal/reports/sample%20reports/departmental%20sales.rdl&rs:Command=Render&rc:Zoom=Whole%20Page&rc:Parameters=collapsed&rc:DocMap=true&rc:Section=2&CategoryID=" & Fields!CategoryID.Value & "&CategoryName="& Fields!CategoryName.Value
```

where **Section** parameter is the page number.

Comment: The thing is, the page the particular table is on could be different depending on how much data is in the first table (based on the time period the user chooses), so I don't think this is flexible enough. Thank you anyways!

Comment: Unfortunately jumping to another report (drillthrough) and to a specific bookmark (internal report navigation link) at the same time is currently not supported.The only way is going to a page/section. I am afraid you cannot do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use bookmarks:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239378.aspx

Add bookmarks and bookmark links to a report when you want to provide a customized table of contents or to provide customized internal navigation links in the report. Typically, you add bookmarks to locations in the report to which you want to direct users, such as to each table or chart or to the unique group values displayed in a table or matrix. You can create your own strings to use as bookmarks, or, for groups, you can set the bookmark to the group expression.