# SSRS Accessing subreport bookmark from parent report

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, bookmarks, subreport

Is it possible to have a textbox link on a main report that uses the Action - Go To Report feature while passing a parameter AND going to a specific Bookmark on the subreport?

In short, a user clicks a text box, a report opens with a provided parameter, and jumps right to a bookmark.

Comment: Please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874871/report-builder-can-i-link-to-a-specific-part-of-a-report). You can jump to a page, but a bookmark inside another report seems not to be supported unfortunately.